# How to find the region of AMI?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

In my Project I have one AMI Image-id. I want find out in which region this AMI runs? Can anyone please explain, how to get it without going to AWS console.

Comment: do you have aws command line tools setup on your machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use AWS ec2 describe images function http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeImages.html

using the AWS command line tools.

alternatively you can use Ruby sdk for AWS

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/